# CIVI EVENTS - Copy and Copy and COPIES of an event - Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Tags: civievent

Copy of BPI Heat Tech Written Test 50 Questions  (ID: 6187)
East Syracuse   New York    BPI Heat Tech Written Test  No  Jun 09, 2014 9:02 AM
Copy of Copy of BPI Heat Tech Written Test 50 Questions  (ID: 6188)
East Syracuse   New York    BPI Heat Tech Written Test  No  Jun 09, 2014 9:02 AM
Copy of Copy of BPI Heat Tech Written Test 50 Questions  (ID: 6189)
East Syracuse   New York    BPI Heat Tech Written Test  No  Jun 09, 2014 9:02 AM
Copy of Copy of BPI Heat Tech Written Test 50 Questions  (ID: 6190)
East Syracuse   New York    BPI Heat Tech Written Test  No  Jun 09, 2014 9:02 AM

There is no ryhme or reason to when it will happen but we have been experiencing this issue for over a year now.  We are up to over 1000 "copy" events in our system with no end in site.   ID numbers are normally not in a row as there are above but scattered.

I was given the follwing response on here, which did no good, I could not find the BAO event copy as described and I also inactivated the repeat event tab.

**TECH RESPONSE**
It doesn't feels like a CiviCRM Core problem to me but I don't know what else it could be either.

The "Copy of" seems to indicate that it use the CRM_Event_BAO_Event::copy as if used by the Copy action in manage event page.

You may check for any custom code that could contains CRM_Event_BAO_Event::copy or something like that.

You could also try to disable CiviCRM extensions or Joomla extensions one by one and see if it keeps happening

We are using:  CiviCRM 4.6.15. Joomla 3.6.2

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue, which I just noticed it yesterday. I'm running Drupal 7.59 w/ CivicRM 5.6.0. However, I have a few extensions installed. I recenly installed the CiviMobile extension, so I just disabled and uninstalled it hoping that this was the one causing the duplications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that these copies exist at a db level? I.e. Are they just showing the same event multiple times? Look at the urls and see if they have different ids to confirm this.

Comment: they all have different id numbers.

Comment: Copy of Combustion Appliance Zone Testing 101  (ID: 6522)


Combustion Appliance Zone Testing 101  (ID: 6132)

Comment: Do you have any custom modules installed?
Do you have CiviRules installed? Is it rigged to create events?
Can anyone log into a portal and create events?
Can events be created in any other way i.e. by sending an email to an address?

Comment: I discovered Civi is copying all current and upcoming events only.  We had "old" events in there because no end was ever inputted.  I am editing the original event with end dates.  Once I start deleting all these "copies", the system then will only copy all new events which will be way more manageable when deleting.  That is all I came up with.

Comment: we manually create events.  I even took out the repeat event option.  No one can log in and create and event.  Under modules  whave tons of itmes but nothing with Civi.  I don't see anything with Civirules.

Comment: no civirules under extensions

Comment: I have 1131 events to delete is there away to get into our file manager to do that; they have to be deleted one by one in Civi?

Comment: Hi. It's interesting. Do these events have participants? Is the number of copies related to the number of participants. You'd need to use phpmyadmin or similar to delete, but that's risky (ie if any had participants this would break things) but far better would be a script with an api call. Suggestion: Recruit a partner to fix for you. And make available here what's in your logs. Also report the bug on issues.civicrm.org. Also turn on logging so the timing of their creation can be tracked.

Comment: CRM_Core_Action::COPY => array(
          'name' => ts('Copy'),
          'url' => CRM_Utils_System::currentPath(),
          'qs' => 'reset=1&action=copy&id=%%id%%',
          'extra' => 'onclick = "return confirm(\'' . $copyExtra . '\');"',
          'title' => ts('Copy Event'),

I Found this

Comment: the copies do not show participants.  When you delete it states "Warning: Deleting this event will also delete associated Event Registration Page and Event Fee configurations. This action cannot be undone. Do you want to continue?"

Comment: I reported the issues they said it wasn't on their end, since I could not "reproduce it" in their demo program.

Comment: Ok. We need to find out what's causing that. Do you have a staging site we can enable backtrace on?

Comment: I don't mean the copies. Does the original event have participants? How many and how many copies?

Comment: no it does not match the number of participants...there are 15 copies to each event right now

Comment: i do not know what a staging site is

Comment: some have more than that

Comment: i looked at one event it had one participant and 13 copies

Comment: I have one event that I stopped counting at 60 copies m- there is one participant.  The longer these have been there the more they get copied over.  Again in "UPCOMING" events even though most have past.  The new events I just delete as they "copy"

Comment: Interesting. Staging site = test site. You're not meant to have stack trace on a live site, and that's ultimately how we'll solve this. Establish if a new copy is created when they're viewed through the website, and look in the log_ tables (do you use phpmyadmin?) to see if there's a pattern. Try running scheduled jobs manually and see if that creates more.

Comment: no I don't use phpmyadmin.  They are events not jobs...we post it on our site through jevents.  I do not know how to run scheduled jobs.  New events in Civi -copies are made as well

Comment: I wish I knew how to do all that you have listed :-(, but I don't

Comment: we use bluehost, I am only the admin sothere are a lot of things I do not know how to do though I maintain our website.

Comment: Jevents may be the problem. Ask bluehost if they hava phpmyadmin installed and if so where. It may be worth asking a partner organisation to help you. Good luck.